What Culture to use with StringBuilder to preserve functionality & performance, and avoid error CA1305
What Culture should I use with StringBuilder.Append to have similar functionality to this code:
StringBuilder sb = string.empty;
string str = ...;

sb.Append($"{str}BLABLA\n");

Is it really possible that I get different results depending on the Culture here, as Visual Studio claims when throwing out error CA135? It seems doubtful because I'm only using a string within the string interpolation.
I'm almost tempted to simply replace the call with two calls to Append to get rid of this...

That's a false warning.  The poster of this issue has a very good point, sad they didn't take them serious.

Thank you for your answer. I'm still quite confused by this Culture stuff.. I can't find a definitive answer about what Culture I should use in this case to preserve functionality, but based on your answer and my initial assumption, it might be the case that any Culture would work here. I don't really know if it's worth adding that Culture parameter in the code, I think I'd rather just use two Append calls, one with str, one with the fixed part. Suppressing the warning does not seem like a good call in case someone uses something other than a string in the interpolation in the future.
